# ncurses: alternative to mvwprintw

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm looking for an alternative to the `mvwprintw` function. My problem is that this function moves the cursor and the puts the text on the screen. Is there an alternative that does the same except it doesn't mess with the cursor position?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're looking for "ANSI Escape Sequence"?   I use these over `ncurses`.

Comment: @Deanie I'm writing a text editor and my codebase is tightly coupled with ncurses. If I'm going to switch to anything else, that means (most likely) abandoning the project and writing everything again. the refactoring is just doesn't pay off in my case, although I'm looking forward to learning more about ncurses alternatives ;)

Comment: Just move the cursor back when you are done printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in another answer, you can always save and restore the cursor position using [`getyx`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getyx.3x.html) (or [`getcurx`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_legacy.3x.html), `getcury`) and `wmove`.

[`mvwprintw`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_printw.3x.html) acts as if it calls [`wmove`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_move.3x.html) and (on success) `wprintw`, which also moves the cursor:

> The printw, wprintw, mvprintw and mvwprintw routines are  analogous  to
> printf  [see printf(3)].  In effect, the string that would be output by
> printf is output instead as though waddstr were used on the given  window.

because [`waddstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html) acts as if it calls [`waddch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html).  There is another set of functions corresponding to `waddstr` which do not move the cursor, i.e., [`waddchstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addchstr.3x.html), but there is no counterpart/non-advancing `wprintw` and `waddch` for that case.  So saving/restoring the cursor is the only way in the curses library for doing what is asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `mvprintw` as you already are, and just move the cursor back.

```
/* first record cursor position */
int x,y;
getyx(win, y, x);

/* your original code */
mvwprintw(win, other_y, other_x, "hello");

/* move back to original location */
wmove(win, y, x);
```

Just note that `getyx` is a macro so you are not sending an address, but `x` and `y` *will* get assigned.